# sistema com CRUD

Tags: java, array

sou graduando em Sistemas e estou desenvolvendo um sistema, e minha  dificuldade é remover de um array um elemento, pois o problema em questão é que quando tem mais de um elemento ele remove normalmente, mas quando tem um só não remove, minha lógica utilizada pra remoção deve ter algum erro, pois não estou conseguindo resolver o problema.

segue abaixo o código que estou fazendo

```
public int buscarImovel(int cod){
    for(int i = 0; i < qtdImoveis; i++) {
        if(imoveis[i].codigo == cod)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
 }
public void deletarImovel(int cod){ 
    int i = buscarImovel(cod);

    if(i >= 0){
        for(int j = i; j < qtdImoveis-1; j++){
            imoveis[j] = imoveis[j + 1];
            qtdImoveis--;
            imoveis[qtdImoveis] = null;

            if(imoveis[j].codigo != cod)
                System.out.println("Não foi encontrado o imóvel com código informado");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bom dia, amigo. Você poderia detalhar mais?
Seria interessante o trecho de código que você está utilizando...

Comment: Sem nos mostrar seu código não temos como ajudá-lo. Outra coisa: Se você precisa inserir e remover elementos, você deve considerar o uso de um  `ArrayList` no lugar de um array normal.

Comment: foi mal, acabei de editar é pq nunca tinha enviado uma pergunta antes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja a sua lógica:

```
for(int j = i; j < qtdImoveis-1; j++){
    imoveis[j] = imoveis[j + 1];
    qtdImoveis--;
    imoveis[qtdImoveis] = null;
}
```

Se o array tiver 1 elemento e você quiser remover este único elemento, o laço `for` acima terá os seguintes valores:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 1-1; j++)
```

Claramente você percebe que o laço nunca será executado, pois `j` é 0 e 0 nunca é menor que `1-1`.

Sugiro fortemente que você use a classe [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) pois ela tem um método específico para remover um elemento. Bastaria chamar:

```
imoveis.remove(i);
```

E o elemento no índice `i`seria removido.